# Importing CSV files to Python and subject and teacher task Python

Tags: python, csv

My task is to create a Python file that imports data from the CSV file I have created:
The python program then must store the CSV columns in a list
The program asks the teacher for 6 subjects which the user must enter
It must then cross reference the imported CSV and produce the name of the teacher:
At the moment, my code can only ask for one subject. If i enter more than 1 subject, it doesnt work. Can someone help me to write a code which asks the 6 subjects and tell each teacher name of each subject? Thanks.

**CODE:**

```
import csv

with open('teachers.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

subjects = []
teachers = []


for row in readCSV:
    subject = row[0]
    teacher = row[1]


    subjects.append(subject)
    teachers.append(teacher)


what_subject = input("Which subjects did you have today at school? ")
subjectdex = subjects.index(what_subject)

theteacher = teachers[subjectdex]

print("The teachers of", what_subject, "are", theteacher)
```

For personal reasons, I can't upload the CSV file since it has personal names.

Comment: use `for` loop to ask for more subjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code which I created with a similar task. Instead of subjects, I used games. Simply change the strings.

```
import csv

price_list = {} # this is an empty dictionary

with open('gamesandprices.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in readCSV:
    price_list[row[0]] = row[1]

what_game = input("Which game(s) would you like to find out the price of?: ")
what_game = what_game.split(' ')

results = [(game, price_list[game]) for game in what_game if game in price_list]

if len(results) > 6:
print('Please ask prices for a maximum of 6 games')
else:
for game, price in results:
    print('The price of {} is {}'.format(game, price))
```

Comment: No problem mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` loop to repeat everything 6 times

```
for x in range(6):
   what_subject = ... 
   subjectdex = ...
   theteacher = ...
   print(...)
```

Or use `split(' ')` if you have subjects in one line of text

```
text = input("subjects (separated by one space): ")

subjects = text.split(' ')

if len(subjects) > 6:
   print("too much subjects")

for s in subjects:
   subjectdex = ...
   theteacher = ...
   print(...)
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
import csv

subjects = []
teachers = []

with open('teachers.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for row in readCSV:
        subjects.append(row[0])
        teachers.append(row[1])

# ---

# for test
#subjects = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']
#teachers = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Q']

what_subject = input("Which subjects did you have today at school? ")

what_subject = what_subject.split(' ')

if len(what_subject) > 6:
    print("too much subjects")

for one_subject in what_subject:

    # find more then one teacher
    theteacher = []
    subjectdex = 0

    while True:
        # find next - start at "subjectdex"
        try:
            subjectdex = subjects.index(one_subject, subjectdex)
        except:
            break # no more subjects - leave loop

        theteacher.append(teachers[subjectdex])

        subjectdex += 1 # new start for "index"

    theteacher = ', '.join(theteacher)

    print("The teachers of", one_subject, "are", theteacher)
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't display anything and I cannot understand.

Comment: you said your program as for one subject but you need 6 - so use `for` loop to repeat the same commands 6 times.

Comment: Or use `split(' ')` and then you can answer 6 subjecs in one line "subject1 subject2 subject3 subject4 subject5 subject6"