# User entering six subjects in a single line of text in Python after importing CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have been working on a code which asks the user to insert six subjects which they had in school today. I want them to insert six subjects in a single line of text and I cannot upload the CSV file for personal reasons.

**HERE IS MY CURRENT CODE:**

```
import csv
with open('teachers.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

subjects = []
teachers = []

for row in readCSV:
    subject = row[0]
    teacher = row[1]

    subjects.append(subject)
    teachers.append(teacher)

text = input("Please insert all the subjects you had today at school(separated by one space): ")

subjects = text.split(' ')

if len(subjects) > 6:
print("too much subjects")

for s in subjects:
   teacherdex = subjects.index(text)
   theteacher = teachers[teacherdex]

   print("The teachers of", text, "are", theteacher)
```

After I press F5 to run the code, and insert the six subjects, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Year 10/Computing/A453/Task Practice/TeachersTask5.py", line 23,    in <module>
teacherdex = subjects.index(text)
ValueError: 'Maths Science English Computing Psychology Sociology' is not in  list
```

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you have already broken down your single line of text in `text` into a list called `subjects` that you are iterating through. You then go back to using `text` rather than your new list. Try:

```
for s in subjects:
   teacherdex = subjects.index(s)
   theteacher = teachers[teacherdex]

   print("The teachers of", s, "are", theteacher)
```

Comment: It works but it displays all of the subjects in the lines. I want it to say: The teacher of Computing is Rebecca. But it displays all the subjects I have entered and then it displays the teacher for the first subject.

Comment: @JasonCole I needed to correct a second reference to `text` sorry. The edit should work now.

Comment: Thanks it works. Thanks alot man. I am marking your answer correct.

Comment: Now my new task is to use the same code but write a sentence and make Python pick out keywords from the sentence and give a value from the CSV file. Any help?

Comment: @JasonCole Was in meetings sorry. What are your ideas for tackling such a problem?

Comment: @JasonCole Can I ask why you have retracted the correct tag for this? You marked it as correct and it is the appropriate answer for your question. If you have additional tasks to complete that were not part of your question but asked an hour later, it is both unfair to then consider the answer incomplete, removing any reward for solving your problem, and now means that there is one more "unanswered" question on the site.

Comment: Sorry for this! I marked the answer correct again. Sorry.

Comment: @JasonCole Ha, no worries mate. Thought it seemed a strange way to try get an on-going answer :P

Answer (score 0):

See new full example for this question on:

[Importing CSV files to Python and subject and teacher task Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34926257/1832058)

BTW: you use the same parts of code which I created for something else :)

Comment: He is a guy in my class :)